# Trying to install pyaudio using pip

Tags: python, windows, pip, x86-64, pyaudio

I try  to  install pyaudio in pycharm,  and

> I get this  error
>
> ```
> error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' 
> failed with exit status 2
> ```

I  used `pip install pyaudio` command.

> Copy comment:

- I downloaded `PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl`
- try to install it using this command

  ```
  pip install PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64
  ```

but it does not work and get this error

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyAudio-0.2.11-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64 (from versions: none) 
ERROR: No matching distribution found for PyAudio-0.2.11-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
pip install pipwin
pipwin install pyaudio
```

pipwin is like pip, but it installs precompiled Windows binaries provided by Christoph Gohlke. Saves you a lot of manual googling and downloading.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is not a solution to your error, but it is one of the easiest ways to install it on Windows.

You can simply grab the proper Wheel package based on current Python version from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio)
and then install it with `pip install <PyAudio‑0.2.11-...>`. Also, there is no need to have MSVC installed.

Comment: I downloaded PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl , and  try to install  it  using this command  pip install PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64  , but it  does not  work and  get this  error  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyAudio-0.2.11-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for PyAudio-0.2.11-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64

Comment: @warda: You have to use `install ...` with extension `.whl`