# error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe'

Tags: python, windows, pip, pyaudio

When I tried to install PYAUDIO on my pc I got this error:

> No such file or directory
>       error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

Before, this I was getting this error:

> error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required

Then I downloaded build tools. After that I got this error:

> No such file or directory
>       error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to install pyaudio using pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55936179/trying-to-install-pyaudio-using-pip)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpyaudio%5D+%5Bpip%5D+%5Bwindows%5D+install

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpyaudio%5D+%5Bpip%5D+install